# Blender 2.9 Shading Workspace. Environment/HDRI showing gray

Tags: shaders, lighting, hdri

[image]I'm a beginner to blender and I was texturing a sword I made from a tutorial, but ran across a problem. In Shading mode, my Hdri is completely gray, the environment is not visible at all. When screen world is not enabled, the lighting from the hdri is visible on my model, but the actual hdri environment is not visible. When screen world is on, all lighting disapears even though in multiple posts I've saw about this problem enabiling screen world was the solution. The hdri I'm using is sunrise.exr. Thanks a lot to anyone that can assist me.[image]

Comment: If your question is about the environment texture, then show the settings for the world, not for the object's material.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are the world settings.

Comment: You mention using an HDR, but in the world there is no environment texture.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you very much.